# Is it possbile to use ms-grid-system in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to use ms-grid-system in my custom index.aspx file? Not on webpart, but on the page to make different `<div>`s more responsive?

EDIT:
Lets say I make a Sharepoint-page for an organization. And as a landing page I create index.aspx. 
Is it possible to use the grid-system in index.aspx, like I use Bootstrap in other pages? In that way I can make responsive sites.

Comment: Uhmm, -- No. Hacking SharePoint with SharePoint Designer is a difficult task. Your question is way too broad. Please edit it and provide more detail.

Comment: are you on SharePoint online or 2013?

Comment: Sharepoint Online

Comment: I don't know much about SharePoint Online, but you can do it SharePoint on-prem. If you can use SharePoint Designer at SharePoint Online, you can do this type of development I guess.